# White space below webparts

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-foundation, web-part-page

I have a web part page and 6 web parts aligned 2x3. However following the web parts there is a lot of white space and I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

The grey box in the first picture is all empty white space.
[image]
[image]

Any way I can get rid of this because it looks pretty bad and cause the page to scroll when it really does not need to.

Comment: is there a CQWP in the mix somewhere that may have extra whitespace in it?  Also, if you hit F12 on the browser and then inspect that area, where does it say it is coming from?

Comment: I think it's coming from the wrapper "s4-workspace" It's set at some fixed height. I tried changing it in the console to 100% but that didn't work.